# Select duplicate rows by comapring multiple columns in R

Tags: r, comparison, rowcount

I have an issue in selecting duplicate rows in R. A data fame has 14 columns and 1 million rows. I have to do row comparison i.e finding out identical rows, would be duplicate. I want to get the duplicate row by this method. My data frame is like 
[Data frame sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Iis9.jpg)

Last two rows were identical, so need to mark it as flag value 1.
I don't know how to start with this.

I have tried these codes,

```
df <- unique(data[,1:97]) //this method gives me unique set not number of duplicates.
dim(data[duplicated(data),])[1]  // this method gives me the number of duplicates but not ids.
```

I need to know the duplicate ids.

my intension is to check each row and written total number of duplicate rows or the line number.

Comment: @dww I have already referred the question. It can remove particular row and column values, but I need to do it for entire row. I have linked in my data sample.

Answer (score -1):

Look into the `duplicated()` function. It can be used to remove the duplicated rows or inversely keep them as well

Comment: I have applied duplicated() function on my set but it says false, even duplicate row exists.